# Open calendar event details using an intent

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am able to open the event details intent directly from Froyo using the following code:

```
Uri eventDetailsUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
Intent eventDetails = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(eventDetailsUri);
startActivity(eventDetails);
```

But the same code doesn't work with Ice cream sandwich. It is showing the Calendar view first for few seconds and then navigating to event details. How can I avoid showing calendar view and directly navigate to event details view?